# Ant Regex Replacement Issue

Tags: regex, ant

Hi i want to replace/add (-SNAPSHOT) to a version from pom.xml. If the version is 1.1.1 i want 1.1.1-SNAPSHOT and when it is already SNAPSHOT to remain the same.

Currently i have this

```
<propertyregex property="snapshotVersionRepl"
                              input="${pom.project.version}"
                              regexp="(.*)(-SNAPSHOT)?"
                              replace="\1-SNAPSHOT"
                              casesensitive="false" />
```

But with input 1.0.0 i get 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-SNAPSHOT , and with 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT i get 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-SNAPSHOT-SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 1):

You may fix the pattern by adding anchors and making the first `.*` lazy:

```
regexp="^(.*?)(-SNAPSHOT)?$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4dCOme/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(-SNAPSHOT)?` - an optional `-SNAPSHOT` sequence
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend avoiding ant-contrib, as it tends to promote bad practices in Ant scripts. Any sort of string manipulation can be accomplished through native Ant's `filterchain` types.

Regarding your regex, Wiktor's pattern works, but in this case I would prefer to use negative lookbehind.

Test Target:

```
<target name="replace-version">
    <property name="pom.project.version1" value="1.1.1" />

    <loadresource property="snapshotVersionRepl1">
        <propertyresource name="pom.project.version1" />
        <filterchain>
            <tokenfilter>
                <replaceregex pattern="(.*)(?&lt;!-SNAPSHOT)$" replace="\1-SNAPSHOT" />
            </tokenfilter>
        </filterchain>
    </loadresource>

    <echo>${snapshotVersionRepl1}</echo>

    <property name="pom.project.version2" value="1.1.1-SNAPSHOT" />

    <loadresource property="snapshotVersionRepl2">
        <propertyresource name="pom.project.version2" />
        <filterchain>
            <tokenfilter>
                <replaceregex pattern="(.*)(?&lt;!-SNAPSHOT)$" replace="\1-SNAPSHOT" />
            </tokenfilter>
        </filterchain>
    </loadresource>

    <echo>${snapshotVersionRepl2}</echo>
</target>
```

Output:

```
 [echo] 1.1.1-SNAPSHOT
 [echo] 1.1.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Note that `&lt;` is used in place of `<` to avoid breaking the XML syntax.